# uninstall visual c++ using batch command

Tags: batch, cmd.exe, visual-c++, redistributable

I am trying to uninstall every single installed version of visual c++ redistributable before installing the updated versions using cmd.

any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't have to uninstall previous versions of Visual C++ in order to install the current versions.  Multiple versions can co-exist on a single system, and need to co-exist, depending on what version of Visual C++ your programs use.  An example of this is that, two seperate programs, can use two different versions of Visual C++ 2015.  If you uninstalled one of those versions, the program that used that version, would not function despite Visual C++ being installed.

Comment: Some of those older redistributables maybe needed by apps that depend on it.  Just install the newer version with all the others.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the answer you're hoping for, but I've never come across an instance where you need to uninstall previous before updating the latest fixes. Also, software will tend to be linked against a certain version - so if you think you can uninstall all VC up to version 2013 because you have just installed 2015, then you'll find all the software that depended on those versions just broke.

Short answer; just upgrade the ones that are there via normal windows update process and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall the VS 2017, please have a try with the syntax similar like

```
vs_enterprise.exe uninstall
```

for more detail information, please check [this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2017#list-of-command-line-parameters).